# How to prevent an svg rect from scaling to the zoomed value, and stay a constant size

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I have an svg item with a icon that I would like to not scale when the user zooms in, but remain the same size. Currently, this is working as expected. However, I am placing a rect outside of the icon that needs to be the same scale and size as the icon, but is still scaled to the zoom value and does not always match. How do I fix this so that the rect is resize when the user zooms.

Here's what I have:

```
const ICON_SIZE = 1;
    <g
      data-id="hive-item"
      id={id}
      transform={`translate(${x}, ${y})`}
      style={{ pointerEvents: locked ? 'none' : 'all' }}
      {...rest}>
      <g transform="scale(1, -1)">
        <WarningIcon
          color={selected ? 'red' : 'black'}
          height={ICON_SIZE / adjustedZoom}
          width={ICON_SIZE / adjustedZoom}
          x={-ICON_SIZE / 2}
          y={-ICON_SIZE / 2}
        />
        <rect
          x={-ICON_SIZE / 2}
          y={-ICON_SIZE / 2}
          width={ICON_SIZE}
          height={ICON_SIZE}
          fill="transparent"
          onClick={onClick}
        />

      </g>
    </g>
```

This is before zooming in

[image]

This is what happens when the user zooms in ( I want the rect to still fit the icon and stay the same size like the icon does)
[image]